# How to set a static IPv6 default route with dhcpcd?

Tags: networking, route, dhcpcd

I am going to set a static IPv6 address and a corresponding IPv6 default route with `dhcpcd`. I have looked through `man dhcpcd.conf`, but to find nowhere mentioning how to set an IPv6 default route.

My current `dhcpcd.conf`:

```
hostname
duid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier

interface eth0
noipv6rs
static ip6_address=2001:xxx::xxx/128
```

What I want `dhcpcd` to do is:

```
ip addr add 2001:xxx::xxx/112 dev eth0
ip -6 route add 2001:xxx::xxxx dev eth0
ip -6 route add default via 2001:xxx::xxxx
```

However, with my current configuration, `dhcpcd` does only the first two lines for me but not the third line.

`man dhcpcd.conf` only tells that an IPv4 default router can be set via something like `static routers=192.168.0.1`.

I know it can be done by `ip -6 route add` manually, using hooks of `dhcpcd`, or simply put aside `dhcpcd`. But I rely on `dhcpcd` to handle DHCPv4. And I think it would less messy if dhcpcd can handle both IPv4 and IPv6 configurations.

My question:

Is there a more direct way where `dhcpcd` sets the IPv6 default route automatically by specifying some options / commands in `dhcpcd.conf`?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot use DHCPv4 to give out default IPv6 routes. You cannot even use [DHCPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCPv6) to give out default IPv6 routes.

The reason is that IPv6 is different from IPv4 in many respects, and one of them is how routers behave: Every IPv6 router announces itself as gateway to the segment which can use it as gateway. And you can have multiple routers for segment, it's not restricted to a single gateway as in IPv4.

Therefore, this doesn't happen by exchanging DHCP broadcasts and replies, but instead it happens by exchanging *router solicitation* (RS) and *router advertisement* (RA) messages between hosts and routers, as defined in the IPv6 [Neighbour Discovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol).

So the only way to make your IPv6 hosts configure themselves with the right route is to run `radvp` (properly configured) in addition to `dhcpd` on your router/gateway. While you are at it, you can enable RS messages again (delete `noipv6rs`), because if Linux considers itself a router (forwarding is enabled) it won't (or at least shouldn't) send out RS messages.

And using `radvp` *is* actually the "less messy" way - it allows you to add routers to or remove routers from your segment without having to update a central configuration file.

In addition, stateless autoconfiguration (SLAAC) will allow your hosts to generate IPv6 addresses from the routeable prefixes themselves.

Comment: Wondering how this works when the system is a router with one interface facing the ISP?  I get an IPv6 from my ISP but default routes aren't appearing in `ip -6 route` and I don't know what's responsible for doing that.  Not sure if I should be pointing `radvd` toward the ISP.

Comment: @LawrenceC: The router gets a prefix from the ISP, and then passes on this prefix on the internal interfaces. Google "IPv6 prefix delegation". Assuming a home router etc., you usually configure `dnsmasq` for that.

Answer (score 4):

Googling for "dhcp ipv6 defaultroute" led me to this AU Q&A titled: [how to set default gateway in dhcpd6.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649547/how-to-set-default-gateway-in-dhcpd6-conf). According to this Q&A IPv6:

> DHCPv6 does not support options to set routers/gateways.

Comment: Confirmed by the current maintainer of dhcpcd: https://roy.marples.name/archives/dhcpcd-discuss/0002149.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer my own question:

The answers by *dirkt* is the direct answer to this question.
The answers by *slm* gives some helpful solutions and further suggestions.

But, neither of them do solve the problem I encounter.

The case I was confronted with is that the network environment is totally out of my control. <del>In fact, I bought a VPS from a VPS provider.</del> What they provide is the preconfigured network. I just wanted to reinstall the VPS and change the OS from Debian to another distro and I have no choice to change any network environment other than reproducing the exact same network configuration after installation.

After searching on the Internet and asking helps other where I find the best workaround to configure a static IPv6 router and address is to use **netctl**. **netctl** can use **dhcpcd** as the backend for negotiating DHCPv4 while also providing simple ways to configure IPv6 statically. Here is my configuration until now:

```
Description='A basic dhcp ethernet connection'
Interface=eth0
Connection=ethernet
IP=dhcp
#DHCPClient=dhcpcd
#DHCPReleaseOnStop=no

IP6=static
Address6=('2001:****:****::****/***')
Routes6=('2001:****:****::****')
Gateway6='2001:****:****::****'
```

Comment: Your actual problem sounds very different from the original question. I probably don't understand the problem description completely, but what prevented you from just using IPv6 static addresses/routes in addition to DHCP? And there's a number of ways to set static IPv6 addresses/routes, depending on the distro.

Comment: Sorry for the lateness. I had strived to make my question clear and avoided to make it specific to my own situation. But it seems that I carelessly omitted some important information so that you got a little confused. The reason for the latter question is: I think it could be less messy to make a network manager to configure them all. Besides, for Arch Linux which I am using, I find no documents describing how to configure static addresses directly.